# How to get the selected row with M13CheckBox pod.. in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Help! I haven't been able to find an answer online. How do you find out the selected row when using the M13CheckBox pod? As there is no delegate method.. from my prototype cell on UIstoryboard it only allows me to reference an action.. any links appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, if the cell has no other responsibility use the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }`

when user selects the cell, alternate the button check state.

Comment: My fault.. added functionality being I am sending the data to fire base so I need to know which one is selected so I can pull it from an array..

Comment: that's fine, by no other responsibility I mean if you have 5 buttons in one cell and you need specific action for each one, if your cell only has one action, do the answer above.

in your didSelectRowAt simply do array[indexPath.row] and get whatever value you need to send to firebase

Comment: yep, don't forget to upvote and select answer if I helped!

Comment: One last thing how do you go about alternating the button to check the state?? Sorry !!

Comment: errr I don't know.. didn't you already use the library? You ask very simple questions... your answer is here https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox#state

Comment: Yep I have seen all this and written a switch case. I’m just a little confused that’s all :)

Comment: I do appreciate your help I am a little closer than I was before :):)

Comment: no prob, don't forget when learning the best thing you can do is read and research about the problem your facing.

Comment: and... according to your answer you don't need a switch state... just do button.setCheckState(newState: .checked , animated: true)

Comment: Perfect !!! That is what I needed ! Thankyou I’m just getting lost in a lot of documentation.. and hours of looking at the screen